# aumix problem- how can I make the changes permenantly

Tags: unix

> Hai every one. How can I make the
>   changes in the aumix permanently? I am
>   running the aumix application using
>   the following command thinapplaunch
>   aumix.
>
> I am increasing the volume manually. I
>   saved and quit.
>
> I am again launching that application
>   using the same command. thinapplaunch
>   aumix   Now all the changes I made is
>   still there. All the volumes are full.
>   But when I logged out and login again
>   the changes is not exists. All the
>   volumes are not full.    How can I
>   make the changes permanently?  Any
>   help much appreciated.   Thanks in
>   Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What distribution are you using? In some distributions you need to create an empty /etc/asound.state.

It seems debian stores it in /var/lib/alsa/asound.state. You can use "sudo alsactl store" to save the state but that should be done automatically. You need to have alsa-utils installed and a symlink in /etc/rc6.d/ so it'll save the state when you shutdown/reboot.

Comment: I am using debian distribution.